# How it will work Synchronization gate way when couchbase lite and couch base server

Tags: synchronization, couchbase, couchbase-lite

1.How the Sync Gateway syncs the data between Couchbase Server and Couchbase lite? Please explain the step by step process how it happens. If possible, please provide sample code.

2.How to sync data using Sync Gateway; only the Latest data that is updated either in the server or in the client when the client changes its state from offline to online? Please provide sample code.

Comment: This is a very broad question, couchbase has getting started guides for multiple platforms. It would be better to ask a more specific question https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/installation/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As an app developer, you should not have to worry about the internals of the sync protocol. If you have `continuous` replication mode enabled then whenever, the client goes offline and then comes back online,  then the sync protocol will automatically determine the changes that have to be synched (push and pull) and it will take place asynchronously in the background. If the `continuous` replication mode is disabled, then the app will have to start the replication when it comes back online. Regardless, even in this case, the sync protocol will identify the changes that have not yet been synched and will handle it.

If you are looking for how to sync data from Couchbase Lite and Sync Gateway, you can refer to the [sample app](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mobile-training-todo).

Here is sample code on how you would do it in [iOS](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mobile-training-todo/blob/master/ios/Todo/AppDelegate.swift#L269).